# iOS7 , Is there a way to disable the transition of UIViewController in UINavigationViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a view controller in navigation controller, its transition was fine until I upgraded my SDK to iOS7.

After upgrading my develop env to iOS7 SDK and Xcode5, I found that I can drag that view out of screen.

The transition looks the same as `popViewController:animated:`'s. After reading the UI transition part of iOS7 doc, I know now that it's a new transition that added in iOS7 SDK.

But, I didn't find how to disable that transition --- just disable the dragging, when I call `popViewController:animated:`, I want that view controller be popped.

Sorry about the complexity of my description. Anybody can give me some hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? It's just a fancy way for the user to dismiss the view controller. It's the same as tapping the "back" button really.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, the doc said that it's the same as the transition of back button. But, my app has a splash view controller which is set as the root of the navigation controller. And if I drag the current view out, the splash view shows and I will be unable to do anything except killing the app.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to drag out the root controller. Or is your main view controller actually pushed on top of the splash view controller? Don't do that.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't do that, but the source is written by someone else and I'm trying to find a quick way to fix this without completely modify the source. Is there any?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking something similar to [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7). If so, here's the code:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```