# How to disable swipe back specifically on only one view controller

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I know there have been similar questions asked, but none of them have worked for me.

I have this code to enable swiping back in my project

```
    class InteractivePopRecognizer: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Properties

    fileprivate weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    // MARK: - Init

    init(controller: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = controller

        super.init()

        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension InteractivePopRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return (navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0) > 1
    }

    // This is necessary because without it, subviews of your top controller can cancel out your gesture recognizer on the edge.
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I have this VC stack

HomescreenVC -> Login/SignupVC -> UserProfileVC

I do not want them to be able to swipe back from the UserProfileVC.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to clear them from the stack when you show `UserProfileVC`

```
let profile  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileID") as! UserProfileVC
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [profile]
```

**Edit:** Do this inside profileVC

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [self]
```

//

```
self.view.alpha = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {

    self.view.alpha = 1

}
```

Comment: I tried putting this in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of userprofilevc but that threw an error, and then i tried putting it after the segues to userprofilevc in the other VC's but that also threw an error.

Comment: remove any segue and give the profile an identifier inside IB , and load it like in answer

Comment: this still doesnt work. I need segues to the view. Is there instead a way to dismiss all the view controllers below the current one (UserProfileVC)?

Comment: yes the edit does not work - I also forgot to mention that UserProfileVC is connected to a tabbar controller, sorry.

Comment: Thank you works well. Just before i accept, is there a way i could animate to the UserProfileVC instead of it just showing up.

Comment: you can't animate the view's frame as it will show black background , but you can animate alpha

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove gesture Recognizer from there too why you are not trying that.
Try something like this:-

view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()

Comment: this doesnt work i can still swipe back. i think its because im instantiating the gesture recognizer on the navigation controller instead of the actual view

Comment: yes it's due to that and checks if on the place of view by putting navigation.
if not working check this http://holko.pl/ios/2014/04/06/interactive-pop-gesture/