# Disable swipe-back for a NavigationLink SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I disable the swipe-back gesture in SwiftUI? The child view should only be dismissed with a back-button.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By hiding the back-button in the navigation bar, the swipe-back gesture is disabled. You can set a custom back-button with `.navigationBarItems()`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("You can swipe back")){
                    Text("Child 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()){
                    Text("Child 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body:some View{
        Text("You cannot swipe back")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Back"){self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but looses you at least the localization (i.e. internationalization) of the back button which you might care about or not.

Comment: is there a way to hide the back button without losing swipe-back?

Comment: @SirVer shouldn't it be fine to use a localized string in your "Back" button? If you care about internationalization, that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: You also lose the back button smartness that it only shows the icon if the title does not fit.

Comment: Another thing you loose by hiding the back button is the ability to long press the back button to show a menu where you can pop many screens back in one go.

Comment: You can set `navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` on the destination itself

Answer (score 7):

Adding this extension worked for me (disables swipe back everywhere, and another way of disabling the gesture recognizer):

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { 
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Introspect library then I just do:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("A view that cannot be swiped back")
           .introspectNavigationController { navigationController in
              navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Only **complete removal of the gesture recognizer** worked for me.
I wrapped it up into a single modifier (to be added to the detail view).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        )
        .disableSwipeBack()
    }
}
```

`DisableSwipeBack.swift`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func disableSwipeBack() -> some View {
        self.background(
            DisableSwipeBackView()
        )
    }
}

struct DisableSwipeBackView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = DisableSwipeBackViewController
    
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        UIViewControllerType()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    }
}

class DisableSwipeBackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.didMove(toParent: parent)
        if let parent = parent?.parent,
           let navigationController = parent.navigationController,
           let interactivePopGestureRecognizer = navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
            navigationController.view.removeGestureRecognizer(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
}
```

> You can resolve the navigation controller without third party by using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in the SwiftUI hierarchy, then access the parent of its parent.

Comment: Doesn't work as of 2023

Answer (score 3):

Setting `navigationBarBackButtonHidden` to true will lose the beautiful animation when you have set the `navigationTitle`.

So I tried another answer

```
navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

But It's not working for me.

After trying the following code works fine

```
NavigationLink(destination: CustomView()).introspectNavigationController {navController in
            navController.view.gestureRecognizers = []
        }
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZImW.gif)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The other ones you end up losing the beautiful iOS animation, as you said.

Comment: So you are using SwiftUI Introspect library?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427754/467209) shows how to configure your navigation controller in SwiftUI (In short, use `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to gain access to the `UINavigationController`).  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7/43199126) shows how to disable the swipe gesture.  Combining them, we can do something like:

```swift
Text("Hello")
  .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
     nc.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
  })
```

This way you can continue to use the built in back button functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The following more replicates the existing iOS chevron image.
For the accepted answer.
That is replace the ***"back"*** with image ***chevron***.

```
 .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Back"){self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
```

With

```
Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}){Image(systemName: "chevron.left").foregroundColor(Color.blue).font(Font.system(size:23, design: .serif)).padding(.leading,-6)}
```