# ScrollView conflicts with NavigationLink swipe-back gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `NavigationLink` view that contains a `ScrollView` that mainly shows a list of contacts. However, the `ScrollView` sometimes register user's pop gesture as a scrolling gesture, thereby preventing the user swipe back out of the `NavigationLink` view.

The general structure is like the follow:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink (destination: AnotherView()) {Text("enter")}
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
             // ... a list of things
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to tell `ScrollView` to ignore the horizontal-ish drag gestures so that `NavigationLink` can be swiped out properly and smoothly?

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438285/disable-swipe-back-for-a-navigationlink-swiftui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by attaching `.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20))` to my `ScrollView` so that the pop gesture of `NavigationView` has a higher priority over `ScrollView`'s gesture.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with TabView.
The following extension solved it:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
}

// Allows swipe back gesture after hiding standard navigation bar with .navigationBarHidden(true).
public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    viewControllers.count > 1
}

// Allows interactivePopGestureRecognizer to work simultaneously with other gestures. 
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    viewControllers.count > 1
}

// Blocks other gestures when interactivePopGestureRecognizer begins (my TabView scrolled together with screen swiping back)
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    viewControllers.count > 1
}
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.