# How to disable `Back` gesture in `NavigationView`?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I need to disallow the `Back` swipe gesture in a view that has been "pushed" in a SwiftUI `NavigationView`.

I am using the `navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` view modifier from the "pushed" view, which obviously hides the standard `Back` button, and partially solves for the requirement.

But users cans still swipe from left to right (going back), which I don't want to allow.

I have tried using `interactiveDismissDisabled`, but this only disables swiping down to dismiss, not "back".

Any suggestions welcome.

[UPDATE] I tried creating a new app with Xcode 14.2, and the `navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` worked as expected:

1. No back button
2. Back swipe gesture disabled

But when I modified the main class of my existing app - with the EXACT SAME CODE as the new test app, it still allowed the back swipe gesture. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Next page") {
                    Text("Page 2")
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, I'm fairly confused. Recreating my existing project, that was created with Xcode 13, will be a substantial task, so I'm trying to figure out what's different. I'm assuming that there is some build setting or configuration option that is somehow influencing this behavior.

Again, any suggestions welcome

Comment: Maybe you could post some code? navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) disables the swiped for me

Comment: Why are you trying to disable the back navigation? There is probably a better way of doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we had the following code in our app that was thought to be unused, but really wasn't, since it was extending `UINavigationController`.

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Uggh.

Comment: This is why it’s not best practice to confirm a type to a protocol when you don’t own at least one of them. Using a subclass would have been better, since it would have made the intention of applying that fix a lot more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

For some cases, it may be necessary to remove the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` from the `UINavigationController`.  The `DisableSwipeBack.swift` example demonstrates this here:  [Disable swipe-back for a NavigationLink SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438285/disable-swipe-back-for-a-navigationlink-swiftui)